# WebRTC In Android

Tags: android, webrtc

I downloaded the open source code of webRtc.In side that I found the WEbRTCDemo test project for Android.I am able to generate the APK BUt when I install it my device not Able to communicate with both device....
Steps What I am doing..
1. In application settings->HostId: I puted Ip Address of other Android device and pressing the start call button but problem is in another Side Nothing happening.

My question is 
1.for communicating the with other Device I have to setUp any server??
2.Can any one explain how its working in case of Android Device.
Please help me.
Thank You
Krishna.

Comment: sorry for that....Now I accepted plz answer me...

Comment: Did you download it from http://www.webrtc.org/

Comment: You need a messaging server. The other demos for WebRTC use the peer_connection_server for messaging between clients. There is no way to do ICE offer/answer without it.

Comment: Where the example app can be found?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you most definitely do need a 'messaging server'. Your task here is to relay the SDP from one client to the other. The SDP includes the ICE Candidates, which basically tells a client how to directly 'reach' the other (IP Address + Port combination). Once both the clients have exchanged these 'handshake' signals, they can start transferring their streams peer to peer.

Now, the implementation of this server is completely left to you. Since it is decoupled from the rest of the WebRTC API, so you can safely resort to any technology to make sure that these signalling messages are exchanged between the two clients. And once you have successfully established a `PeerConnection`, you can from there on even use the `DataChannels` to re-negotiate.

To sum things up,

1. Yes you do need a server to relay the messages between two clients.
2. Since this is independent of the WebRTC implementation, you can resort to any technology of your choice.

Comment: I'm not sure that in the particular WebRTCDemo for android any server is needed as we can set the remote ip address in the settings.